# Convert a .NET Core Console App to run as a continuous background service on Azure

Tags: .net, function, azure, .net-core, console-application

I have a .NET Core Console App that I want to run as a background service that never stops on Azure. Should I convert the Console App to an Azure Function or a Web Job?

How can I run the Function (if that is the best option) without stopping? I have been playing around with running the function with a timer trigger that runs every minute but I am not sure what that does. Would it run the job every minute for a minute and then run a new instance after that? Is there a way to say run function and do not stop running? For now I am using a while(true) loop but I am not sure what I am doing is the proper way to do something like this.

Comment: Well could you update question with what are you doing? maybe you dont even need to run while loop?

Comment: Azure function has limit of max execution time, also you pay for usage, so its not optimal

Comment: How about to package the app into a container and run it on Azure Container Instances? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/container-instances/

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like a perfect fit for a Continuous WebJob.

A Continuous WebJob

> Starts immediately when the WebJob is created. To keep the job from ending, the program or script typically does its work inside an endless loop. If the job does end, you can restart it.
>
> Runs on all instances that the web app runs on. You can optionally restrict the WebJob to a single instance.

More info to be found at [Run Background tasks with WebJobs in Azure App Service](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/webjobs-create)

Answer (score 0):

One option I am thinking about is to have VM and run that service there.

Other option as you said run trigger every X period, but dont run your job for long do your job and keep in mind that you are limited by max 5 minutes(Can be more [read here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-scale#timeout)).

If you run trigger your job will start in same instance(But you should not care where it starts). Function host will be shutdown after sometime of inactivity. Also keep in mind that azure function can scale and you can have same job run in multiple instances